# Does Azure Communication Services (ACS) dispatch a 'participantStateChanged' event when a call is dropped?

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-communication-services

[Quickstart: Use the Communication Services calling client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/calling-client-samples?pivots=platform-web)

> FAQ

- If network connectivity is lost, does the call state change to 'Disconnected' ?

  - Yes, if network connection is lost for more than 2 minutes, call will transition to Disconnected state and call will end.

According to Microsoft Azure docs, if network connectivity is lost the call will end.

Does Azure Communication Services (ACS) dispatch a `participantStateChanged` event when the call is dropped? We need to listen to this event in JavaScript client.

If network connectivity is lost, does ACS dispatch a  `participantStateChanged` event that can be subscribed to in the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We reviewed some call logs and verified that after a `participantRemoved` event is recorded a `participantStateChanged` is always recorded as well.