# Azure ACS - Is there an REST API call to query by groupId to determine the status of a call?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-communication-services

ACS - Azure Communication Services.

Is there an ACS REST API to query by groupId to determine the status of a call?

When a call is ended by a lost network connection, we need a way to query the status of the dropped call in case the `participantStateChanged` event is not received by the client because the browser was closed.

This question is a follow up to this stackoverflow question:

[Does Azure Communication Services (ACS) dispatch a 'participantStateChanged' event when a call is dropped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65622425/does-azure-communication-services-acs-dispatch-a-participantstatechanged-eve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We verified internally that this capability does not currently exist within ACS.

Please keep in mind that ACS is currently in public preview and will become more feature rich as it nears Global Availability (GA). The product group would enjoy receiving feedback regarding this scenario and how you would use this functionality. Please make a feedback request on their [GitHub site](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/issues).